# My testnet baker doesn't produce much

Tags: ledger, baker, delegating

I am trying to bake on testnet carthagenet. I got a

- VPS on AWS with node full sync
- a laptop with tezos-client (connected to rpcalpha.tzbeta.net ) + ledger nano S

My setup:

```
cat ~/.tezos-node/config.json 
{ "p2p":
    { "bootstrap-peers":
        [ "34.76.169.218", "34.90.24.160", "carthagenet.kaml.fr",
          "104.248.136.94" ], "listen-addr": "[::]:9732" },
  "network": "carthagenet" }

tezos-client bootstrapped
Current head: BMXWTx7PQtw3 (timestamp: 2020-10-29T14:52:33-00:00, validation: 2020-10-29T14:53:35-00:00)
Bootstrapped.

tezos-client list known contracts
t2: tz1eijbPSDgjYFC7wRW2u3uyhW7H1TJbnABT
cat: tz1YdaJWrDdHz4qfVEhPEs7f5EBy4DE2Fzv1
bob: tz1MobkJA1cr9oLh8RG5GACRcP1tp8NzXgAu
alice: tz1QhZcFqav2e7VncST5xbGFmAn6z4FUcToe

tezos-client get balance for bob
45668.597577 ꜩ

tezos-client register key bob as delegate
```

Seems delegation succeeded with 5 rolls [tezblock](https://carthagenet.tezblock.io/account/tz1MobkJA1cr9oLh8RG5GACRcP1tp8NzXgAu?tab=Delegations)

I started all binaries and waited 1 day:

```
tail -n10 -f *.out
==> accuser.out <==
Oct 29 14:48:48 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.denunciation: Block BMCcNhH5Daa6 registered
Oct 29 14:50:37 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.denunciation: Block BLRbMPHQZLu6 registered
Oct 29 14:51:28 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.denunciation: Block BMAB5JT8S2tc registered
Oct 29 14:51:57 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.denunciation: Block BMZF5B5eJZMP registered
Oct 29 14:52:34 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.denunciation: Block BMXWTx7PQtw3 registered
Oct 29 14:55:09 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.denunciation: Block BLXD8baHYCNz registered
Oct 29 14:55:51 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.denunciation: Block BM45ja6inK5i registered
Oct 29 14:56:24 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.denunciation: Block BKieB15aQCXS registered
Oct 29 14:56:59 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.denunciation: Block BMA1A2LThstF registered
Oct 29 14:57:30 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.denunciation: Block BLoLu4dXd17J registered

==> bake.out <==
Oct 29 14:48:48 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 837284 (max_priority = 64)
Oct 29 14:50:37 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 837285 (max_priority = 64)
Oct 29 14:51:28 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 837286 (max_priority = 64)
Oct 29 14:51:58 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 837287 (max_priority = 64)
Oct 29 14:52:34 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 837288 (max_priority = 64)
Oct 29 14:55:09 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 837289 (max_priority = 64)
Oct 29 14:55:51 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 837290 (max_priority = 64)
Oct 29 14:56:24 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 837291 (max_priority = 64)
Oct 29 14:56:59 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 837292 (max_priority = 64)
Oct 29 14:57:30 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.forge: No slot found at level 837293 (max_priority = 64)

==> endorser.out <==
Waiting for the node to be synchronized with its peers...
Node synchronized.
Endorser started.

==> node.out <==
Oct 29 14:56:58 - prevalidator.NetXjD3HPJJjm.PsCARTHAGazK: switching to new head BMA1A2LThstFA1UZXSppUwWthAYkZcxZ1uwMUAZrRzkGk14ShjB
Oct 29 14:56:58 - prevalidator.NetXjD3HPJJjm.PsCARTHAGazK:  Request pushed on 2020-10-29T14:56:58-00:00, treated in 943us, completed in 11.477ms 
Oct 29 14:56:58 - validator.chain: Update current head to BMA1A2LThstFA1UZXSppUwWthAYkZcxZ1uwMUAZrRzkGk14ShjB (level 837291, timestamp 2020-10-29T14:56:57-00:00, fitness 01::00000000000cc6aa), same branch
Oct 29 14:56:58 - validator.chain: Request pushed on 2020-10-29T14:56:58-00:00, treated in 387us, completed in 23.39ms 
Oct 29 14:57:30 - validator.block: Block BLoLu4dXd17JXUZYm4zHifh5p2tuPvtxGppo8WdoaBn785uiQij successfully validated
Oct 29 14:57:30 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-10-29T14:57:30-00:00, treated in 122us, completed in 119ms 
Oct 29 14:57:30 - prevalidator.NetXjD3HPJJjm.PsCARTHAGazK: switching to new head BLoLu4dXd17JXUZYm4zHifh5p2tuPvtxGppo8WdoaBn785uiQij
Oct 29 14:57:30 - prevalidator.NetXjD3HPJJjm.PsCARTHAGazK:  Request pushed on 2020-10-29T14:57:30-00:00, treated in 1.672ms, completed in 11.741ms 
Oct 29 14:57:30 - validator.chain: Update current head to BLoLu4dXd17JXUZYm4zHifh5p2tuPvtxGppo8WdoaBn785uiQij (level 837292, timestamp 2020-10-29T14:57:29-00:00, fitness 01::00000000000cc6ab), same branch
Oct 29 14:57:30 - validator.chain: Request pushed on 2020-10-29T14:57:30-00:00, treated in 3.330ms, completed in 23.732ms
```

But,

1. I got an error message on this command:

```
tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/baking_rights\?cycle=300\&delegate=tz1MobkJA1cr9oLh8RG5GACRcP1tp8NzXgAu\&max_priority=2
Command failed : The seed for cycle 300 has been cleared from the context  (oldest known seed is for cycle 405)
```

2. And I can not delegate more Tez from another (ledger) account

```
tezos-client set delegate for ledger_rc to tz1MobkJA1cr9oLh8RG5GACRcP1tp8NzXgAu
Warning: ...
Error:
  Erroneous command line argument 6 (tz1MobkJA1cr9oLh8RG5GACRcP1tp8NzXgAu).
  no public key hash alias named tz1MobkJA1cr9oLh8RG5GACRcP1tp8NzXgAu
```

3. I don't see any blocks getting produced, or my balance `45,668`tz increasing [tezblock](https://carthagenet.tezblock.io/account/tz1MobkJA1cr9oLh8RG5GACRcP1tp8NzXgAu?tab=Delegations)

Anything I am missing?
How do you monitoring if you bake well, if everything is in order?

Thank you for your help!
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This RPC you tried: `/helpers/baking_rights?cycle=300`
   You received an error because cycle 300 is WAYYYY old. The current carth cycle is 405 and the default behavior of tezos-node is to only keep a certain amount of data (7 cycles back) and purge the older stuff. If you want data from older cycles, you must run an archive node which keeps everything.
2. You need to import your baker address into the tezos client. The client is very stupid on this and it *should* accept an address but it doesn't always for every function. Then you can say `set delegate for ledger_rc to bobsBakery`
3. Baking rights are calculated 5 cycles in the future. Since you just became a baker, you have to wait for the next cycle to see your rights, which will be 5 cycles in the future. As carthnet goes at 2x speed of mainnet, your first bake might come in a few days rather than a month (on mainnet).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: 1. OK this command not be useful to monitor my rights
2. I register baker: `tezos-client add address chef tz1MobkJA1cr9oLh8RG5GACRcP1tp8NzXgAu`, delegate with `tezos-client set delegate for ledger_rc to chef`
3. OK, mainnet is 25 days, so I guest I will see some info change on this page https://carthagenet.tezblock.io/account/tz1MobkJA1cr9oLh8RG5GACRcP1tp8NzXgAu?tab=Delegations 12 day after I start my baker on testnet?
4. No other way to monitor if I am well registered, or when baking will start. On mainnet, only after 24 days we know if things works well...

Comment: 1. That command is indeed useful to monitor your rights. You just need to monitor the correct cycle and not some cycle from 6 months ago. 3. Sounds about right. 4. Correct. There isn't much monitoring you can do other than this.

Comment: @greg Please mark as answered to close the question

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications @utdrmac !